# How can I improve this Linq Multiple OrderBy Generic method?

Tags: linq, generics, lambda, sql-order-by, expression

Will the following multiple OrderBy work?

```
products.OrderBy<MyType>(sortPrm[0], sortPrm[1]).OrderBy<MyType>(sortPrm[3],sord);
```

I am using a custom OrderBy generic method shown below that does not return an IOrderedQueryable so I cannot call the ThenBy method. sortPrm is just a string array that holds my sort column and sort direction information created from a string input split into an array using delimiters

```
    public static IQueryable<T> OrderBy<T>(this IQueryable<T> query, string sortColumn, string direction)
    {
        string methodName = string.Format("OrderBy{0}",
            direction.ToLower() == "asc" ? "" : "descending");

        ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");

        MemberExpression memberAccess = null;
        foreach (var property in sortColumn.Split('.'))
            memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property
               (memberAccess ?? (parameter as Expression), property);

        LambdaExpression orderByLambda = Expression.Lambda(memberAccess, parameter);

        MethodCallExpression result = Expression.Call(
                  typeof(Queryable),
                  methodName,
                  new[] { query.ElementType, memberAccess.Type },
                  query.Expression,
                  Expression.Quote(orderByLambda));
        return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
    }
```

EDITED:
It does seem to work with the query generated something like below:
The only wierd thing is that the orderby columns are reversed in the query generated; so I just reversed the order in which I put them:

```
products.OrderBy<MyType>(sortPrm[3],sord ).OrderBy<MyType>(sortPrm[0],sortPrm[1]);
```

this is the query generated:

```
   {SELECT [t1].[value] // all the columns selected
...
...
    FROM (
        SELECT CONVERT(Int,[t0]. // all the columns selected
...
... AS [t0]
        ) AS [t1]
    ORDER BY [t1].[/*my LAST orderby column*/], [t1].[[/*my FIRST orderby column*/] //Note the order is reversed
    }   System.Linq.IQueryable</*my iqueryable class*/> {System.Data.Linq.DataQuery</*my iqueryable class*/>}
```

Comment: Why do you use custom orderby?

Comment: I don't fully understand what the repeated `MemberExpression.Property` does, but `sortColumn.Split('.').Reverse()` should do the job.

Comment: @Likurg Custom orderby allows user specified parameters for sorting at runtime saves me from long loops or switches checking for the parameters